# Trying update dropdown select element without reloading using Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I wasn't finding what I needed so here is my problem. I have to use Vanilla Javascript for this project by the way. I am trying to create an owner and adding it to a '' dropdown menu. The good news is I am able to add it to the dropdown but the bad news is I have to reload my page to see the dropdown update with my new created owner name. The question is how do I accomplish updating my dropdown dynamically without page refresh? **Just an fyi, I cannot use jquery for this.**

Here is some of my relavent code:

Here is my html:

```
<form id = "owner_form">
        <div>
          <label for='name'>Owner Name:</label>
          <input type='text' id='name' name='name' placeholder="John Doe" >
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for='phone_number'>Phone Number:</label>
          <input type='text' id='phone_number' name='phone_number' placeholder="John Doe" >
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for='real_estate_agent'>Listing Agent:</label>
          <input type='text' id='real_estate_agent' name='real_estate_agent' placeholder="John Doe">
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type='submit' id='owner_submit' value='Submit'/>
        </div>
      </form>

      //The target dropdown is in a seperate form but I will only show the relevant part
      
       <form id = "listing_form">
      <div>
        <label for='name'>Owner Name:</label>
        <select id='owner_id' name='owner_id' >
          
        </select>
      </div>
```

//right here is me making my post fetch request to the backend to create owner and post it to database

```
 ownerForm.addEventListener('submit', (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault()
        const formData = new FormData(ownerForm)
        fetch(OWNERS_URL,{
          method: 'POST',
          header: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              "Accept": "application/json"
          },
          body: formData 
        }).then(resp => resp.json()).then((owner_obj) => {
        let option = document.createElement('option');
        option = owner_obj.name;
        dropdown.append(option)
        console.log(owner_obj)
        })
      })
```

**I am not sure if this part will be relevant but here is my fetch request to GET my owners from my source and display them in the dropdown**

```
fetch(OWNERS_URL)
    .then((resp) =>{
        if(resp.status !== 200){
            console.warn('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + 
          resp.status);  
        return;    
        }
        resp.json().then((data) =>{  
            
        
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                let option;
                option = document.createElement('option');
              
                option.text = data[i].name;
                // debugger
                option.value = data[i].id; 
                dropdown.add(option); 
                console.log(option)
            }    
          }); 

    }
    )
    .catch(function(err) {  
        console.error('Fetch Error -', err);  
      });
```

I have researched many examples for they were mostly Jquery which I am not familiar with yet which is why I was having a tough time finding what I needed. Any help on this will be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: When you submit the form, do you get a log with the console.log(owner_obj) ?

Comment: @spangle, it does log what I submitted with all key values. I was previously having issues submitting data before which is what that was there

Comment: try updating option = owner_obj.name; to be option.textContent = owner_obj.name;

Comment: @Spangle....that actually worked. Post that as an answer and I will give it a dumbs up for sure! Thank you sir!!

Comment: Happy to have helped :) Will do now

Comment: I meant thumbs, sorry

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above in the comments, you just need to change the following:

```
option = owner_obj.name;
```

To be the following:

```
option.textContent = owner_obj.name;
```